# How to manage multiple problems in Python 3 on a multicore machine

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm solving game positions.  I generate them in groups of about 3,000.  On my fastest machine, each can take from 6 minutes on up.  I had one running for 2 weeks before I decided on a different approach, so I'll want to abort after maybe an hour (scaled by processor speed,) and subdivide the problem.

The code itself is pretty small.  It optionally uses a cache, for about a 2x speedup, but of course the cache can use a lot of memory.

Right now, I'm managing all this manually, and I can't come close to keeping the machines busy.

I have 2 Core i-7's, a 16-core Xeon (with over 1000 nVidia GPU cores), and some smaller machines to throw at this, but I'd be happy to start with a one-computer solution.

There's an sqlite3 database already in use to hold results, and it could also be part of the solution.

There are enough Python tools for me to be wondering which one(s) to explore.  I've been looking at threading, multiprocess, subprocess, and the pyzmq package.

Frankly, I'm on overload thinking about this, and could use some direction.

Comment: What specifically are you asking? You may want to look at [ask].

Comment: If I knew enough to be specfic, I would be.  I tried giving a general description of what I'm trying to do, the tools that offer some hope of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with GPU programming, but on the CPU side, you might want to start with forking in the `os` module. When your program forks, what happens is you end up, conceptually, with a clone (child) of the original instance of the program (parent process). If you run the `demo_forking` function, you'll see that you can saturate up to `HELPERS` cores. Hopefully that's enough to get started; you'll have to figure out how to partition your problem across multiple processes. I've been out of touch with Python and desktop programming, in general, for a while, but Python wouldn't be my first choice for programming a multicore system due to some of its limitations. That being said, if you already know Python, then maybe it's the most suitable for your application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

HELPERS = 10 # If set to the number of CPU cores or greater, can saturate the core.

def helper(i):
    '''Do part of the work.

    This thread just eats up CPU cycles for i-seconds.'''
    print('Working on part', i, 'of the task.')
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + i:
        pass

    print('Done part', i, ' of the task.')

def demo_threading():
    '''Use threads system to run tasks in parallel.

    Because Python is really only single-threaded, this doesn't saturate a
    multi-core system; it can only saturate a single core.'''
    import threading

    threads = []
    for i in range(HELPERS):
        thd = threading.Thread(target=helper, args=[i])
        thd.start()

    # Wait for all the helper threads to stop.  
    [thd.join() for thd in threads]

def demo_forking():
    '''Use forking to run tasks in parallel.'''
    import os

    processes = []
    for i in range(HELPERS):
        process = os.fork()
        # We now have two identical copies of the process.
        if process == 0:
            # This is the child process.
            helper(i)
            return          # Don't spawn more processes from the child process.
        else:
            # This is the parent process.
            processes.append(process)

    # Wait for all the child processes to stop.
    [os.waitpid(pid, 0) for pid in processes]
```

http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/multicore_python.html

Comment: `multiprocessing` encapsulates the action of forking and keeps you from having to make system calls and checks against the process ID.